# App crashes with "Error: ENOENT" even if persistent folder exist

Tags: node.js, sails.js, digital-ocean, fs, dokku

Lets assume my digitalocean/dokku/nodejs/sails app is called `example.com` and is (will be) available via corresponding domain.

I have added a persistent storage for my app by:

```
dokku docker-options:add example.com run "-v /home/dokku/_work_:/_work_"
dokku docker-options:add example.com deploy "-v /home/dokku/_work_:/_work_"
```

If I run `dokku run example.com "ls /app/_work_"` or `dokku run example.com "ls /app/_work_/uploads"`I can see that the folder exists and there are files/folders there.

Ok, now in my app code I want to check folders in `/app/_work_/uploads` folder and delete some old ones. To do that I first try to get list of folders in `/app/_work_/uploads` by:

```
...
var p = path.join(sails.config.rootPath, '_work_/uploads');
var dirs = fs.readdirSync(p);
...
```

The problem is that my code fails with the following error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/app/_work_/uploads'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.readdirSync (fs.js:808:18)
    at cleanDirs (/app/config/bootstrap.js:36:16)
    at Object.module.exports.bootstrap (/app/config/bootstrap.js:21:2)
    at Sails.runBootstrap (/app/node_modules/sails/lib/app/private/bootstrap.js:44:25)
    at Sails.wrapper [as runBootstrap] (/app/node_modules/sails/node_modules/lodash/index.js:3095:19)
    at Sails.initialize (/app/node_modules/sails/lib/app/private/initialize.js:68:9)
    at wrapper (/app/node_modules/sails/node_modules/lodash/index.js:3095:19)
    at /app/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:713:13
    at iterate (/app/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:262:13)
    at /app/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:274:29
    at /app/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:16
    at /app/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:718:17
    at /app/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:167:37
    at /app/node_modules/sails/lib/app/load.js:184:13
    at /app/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:52:16
    at /app/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:548:17
    at /app/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:542:17
    at _arrayEach (/app/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:85:13)
    at Immediate.taskComplete (/app/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:541:13)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:383:17)
```

How can that be if `/app/_work_/uploads` and there are folders there if I check manually?

Comment: Are you sure permissions for that folder are OK?

Comment: yes, 100% confident to have read/write permissions.

Answer (score 2):

It turned out that event if you have files visible via `ls` command directly and through `docker run <app> <command>` the application cannot see them. In order to fix that instead of

```
dokku docker-options:add example.com run "-v /home/dokku/_work_:/_work_"
```

you have to add `/app/` to the second part of the command by

```
dokku docker-options:add example.com run "-v /home/dokku/_work_:/app/_work_"
```

You will get the same `ls` or `dokku run ..` outputs but, most important, your app will be able now to access files.

I will appreciate if someone could link me on why `ls` worked in both cases, but only by adding `/app` prefix the problem was solved.